# The "MailTo" ...setting a proper name on the Recipient

Tags: html

How do I set a proper name for the recipient when in HTML I want to use the "mailto" tag.

Something like:

```
mailto:"John Wayne(jw@email.com)?subject..
```

How do I achieve that ??

Answer (score 33):

The original standard for `mailto:` links, [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738), says this:

> A mailto URL takes the form:
>
> ```
> mailto:<rfc822-addr-spec>
> ```
>
> where `<rfc822-addr-spec>` is (the encoding of an) `addr-spec`, as
> specified in RFC 822 [[6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738)].

Under that definition, addr-spec is of the form "local-part@domain", so no proper name could be included.

But the `mailto:` section of RFC 1738 was first superseded by [RFC 2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368), which allows (among other things, including predefined subject lines) for an [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822) `mailbox` specification—which includes a proper name.

[2016-05-31] As David Balažic points out in a comment, RFC 2368 is in turn obsoleted by [RFC 6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068). From Section 9, “Main Changes from RFC 2368”:

> The main changes from [RFC 2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) are as follows:
>
> - Changed syntax from [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) `<mailbox>` to [[RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322)] `<addr-spec>`.

An RFC 5322 `<addr-spec>` is of the same "local-part@domain" form as mentioned above, so once again, no name can officially be included.

In actual use, `mailto:Fred Foo<foo@example.com>` still seems to work, but it’s not officially supported; you may also have to encode the space, *i.e.*, `mailto:Fred%20Foo<foo@example.com>`, and/or put the name in quotes, *i.e.*, `mailto:"Fred Foo"<foo@example.com>`.

Comment: Note that that RFC 2368 is obsoleted by [RFC 6068](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6068) , which defines _addr-spec    = local-part "@" domain_ , so it seems display name is not allowed in it.

Answer (score 20):

Try this: `mailto:%22John%20Wayne%22%3cjw@email.com%3e?subject..`

Wrap the name in `%22` and the email has `%3c` before it and `%3e` after it and `%20` for spaces

That will output: `"John Wayne"<jw@email.com>`

Full list of URL Encoding here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: Great, thanks for the ref. BTW: the %22 around the display name are not required.

Comment: This is not standards-compliant.

Comment: Doesn't work with the Mail application in Windows 10. Using `mailto:John Wayne<jw@email.com>` (with or without encoding the space between first and last names) does work.

Comment: @Aaron I would disregard any results with the Windows 10 Mail app - it is as far away from standards as IE5/6/7 ever were - it doesn't even respect the `Reply-To` header field.

Comment: Fair call @Jake.

Answer (score 7):

I tried

```
mailto:John Wayne<jw@email.com>?subject...
```

and it seems to work.

Comment: Where did you try this? It definitely *works not* for me.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in other answers, [RFC 2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) allows the full `mailbox` syntax, which can be in `name-addr` (`display-name` plus `angle-addr`) form ([RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4)). Unfortunately, it was obsoleted by [RFC 6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068), which only allows `addr-spec` form. However, both specifications allow omitting the URI authority (where the to-address usually goes) and specifying full header fields (including `To:`) as query parameters. Therefore, `mailto:?to=John%20Wayne%20%3cjw@email.com%3e` is valid.

Comment: For me `mailto:?to=John%20Wayne%20%3cjw@email.com%3e` does work with ubuntu+evince+thunderbird, but it does not work with windows7+firefox+outlook. However `mailto:John%20Wayne%20%3cjw@email.com%3e` works with both.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <a href="mailto:lala lala2(astark1@unl.edu)?subject=MailTo Comments&cc=ASTARK1@UNL.EDU&bcc=id@internet.node">ddddd</a>
```

**Remember** to use only one ? (question mark), when providing multiple entries beyond e-mail address

Comment: Not sure if it really tackles my original question :-)  where is the Name of the recipient on the TO part?

Comment: @SFDeveloper: I believe "lala lala2" is the name of the recipient in this example.

Answer (score -1):

This all depends on what mail client you use. I've tried that long before at Outlook express and it's ok. But after many years, I use Dream Mail and it will only bring in the mail address part while leave out the name part.

Answer (score -1):

**Encode the uri and assign it to mailto**.

Also your email and display name need to be formed as either `John Wayne <jw@email.com> or jw@email.com (John Wayne)`.

Make sure you did encodeURI for these. Else it wont work properly in different mailclients.

Comment: I think **encodeURI()** can just solve the purpose. Instead of adding the %22 or any characters to add space or parenthesis.  I don't know why its downvoted too.

Answer (score -6):

You can't set the receipt name on mailto links

Comment: sorry for the last comment . I was the stupid who didnt read the question properly.

Comment: Yes you can; see the other answers.