# Using Chrome's "Copy email address" on mailto link returns encoded useless text instead of a correct email address

Tags: php, google-chrome, mailto

We have a website with restricted access (only for exclusive members) coded in PHP.

On the *Contact page* we have a bunch of `mailto` links, for example:

```
<a href="mailto:Name SURNAME <address@domain.com>">address@domain.com</a>
```

If a visitor clicks on one of the links, it does the usual stuff (opens a new email in Thunderbird with the To: field correctly filled in).

The problem is when a visitor *right-clicks* on one of the links, selects "*Copy email address*" and then pastes it in the To: field or wherever (even in a document), in which case the result would be:

> Name%20SURNAME%20%3Caddress@domain.com%3E

instead of

> Name SURNAME <address@domain.com>

I've been searching for a solution for hours and already tried `rawurlencode(), urlencode()` and other possible tricks, with absolutely no effect.

Can some of you please help me?

Here is the PHP code that generates the link:

```
<?php  echo '<a href="mailto:'.$name.' <'.$email.'>'.'">'.$email.'</a>'; ?>
//where $email is a valid email address
//and $name is plain text (usually two words with a space character between)
```

Comment: Perhaps start by providing the code that's generating this link?

Comment: I edited it - the code is visible now.

Comment: No no, where is the PHP code that generated the link?

Comment: Sorry... edited again. I'm new to asking questions on Stackoverflow...

Comment: @JonStirling - as you can see, I'm not using any encoding on the mailto link... :(

Comment: I think this might just be a browser thing rather than anything that you can change since it seems Chrome just copies what is after mailto:. As mailto is a url, it's url encoded which is why you get the encoded versions of certain characters.

Comment: So you say there is absolutely no workaround for this?
I have to mention that this problem started a few months ago, although we never change the code that generates the link...

Comment: I can't think of one that would work for both e-mail clients, _and_ for copy email address.

Comment: But is there one that can work only for copy email address?

Comment: Sure, just put an email address in and nothing else, i.e. `mailto:myemailaddress@test.com` but using your $email variable. That'll work for both, but you lose the "friendly" name bit when it opens in an e-mail client. (personally I'd just go down the simple e-mail route).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're trying to do something that simply cannot be done.
I understand the idea but... it's not a thing.

I found no docs saying that you can put a name and enclose the email address in <>.

1. [https://developer.mozilla.org/.../a#Creating_an_email_link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Creating_an_email_link)
2. [https://developer.mozilla.org/.../Creating_hyperlinks#E-mail_links](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks#E-mail_links)
3. [IETF RFC6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068#section-6)

You can of course do:

```
<a href="mailto:address@domain.com">address@domain.com</a>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your oppinion!
It worked just fine until a few months ago and it's still working if the user is not copying the email address...
Is there another way to include names in the mailto link?

Comment: To my knowledge it is not a supported feature in HTML as a whole.

Answer (score -2):

I found this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25854290/3376036.

It seems it's actually not supported but it usually works

Comment: What's "usually"? Just linking a 7 year old post might not really be a constructive answer.

Comment: Poor choise of words from my part, I wanted to say that the standard says it's not possible but many browsers implement (or implemented in this case) this functionnality
Since this specifications are still true I thought it was still relevant to the problem but I guess I was wrong