# mailto from script not displaying friendly name

Tags: javascript

I am triggering a mailto link from my script and the friendly name the address is not displaying:

```
window.open(`mailto:"${name}"<{contactId=${id}}{userId=${this.userId}}{pitchingInitiativeId=${this.pitchingInitiativeId}}@propelmymail.com>`, '_blank');
```

outputs to:

```
mailto:%22undefined%22%3C%7BcontactId=1%7D%7BuserId=7%7D%7BpitchingInitiativeId=71%7D@propelmymail.com%3E
```

Comment: can you please post what is actually rendering by this script?

Comment: added above, this is what the browser reads it as

Comment: name seems to be an undefined value, try to log it in console and see if it has a value. try console.log(name)

Comment: yea I fixed that part, but it did not solve the problem. when it loads in any mail client, it's still showing the address and not the friendly name

Comment: try this.name instead of name, it is hard to figure out what's going on with just this code, you might want to share some more of your code

Comment: did you get rid of the undefined ? if so can you share the new output.
you might also want to take a look at this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147805/the-mailto-setting-a-proper-name-on-the-recipient

Answer (score 0):

Your output getting generated wrongly, If should be

```
window.open(`mailto:"Friendly Name"<actualemail@propelmymail.com>`, '_blank');
```

In your output there are URL encoded strings are there, I am not sure which js framework you are using but in the plain javascript you can concate placehoders and make string with standards,

```
var name = 'Friendly Name';id = 10; userId = 1125; pitchingInitiativeId = 55;
window.open(`mailto:"${name}"<${id}${userId}${pitchingInitiativeId}@propelmymail.com>`, '_blank');
```

Comment: your syntax is incorrect. you are mixing single quotes and template literals

Comment: @SandraWillford  updated, this is just an Idea you can implement with your desire framework

Comment: @programtreasures: This is backtick. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals